# getaddrinfo()：temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: c, linux, web-crawler

I am writing a web-spider program with C. Now I am given a url's list, and first I need to get the server IP address using function: `getaddrinfo`, and then ridiculous thing happended:

In the url's list there are about 4,000,000 url's, the first about 6,000 url's are processed very well, and then suddenly all of the url's behind failed! `getaddrinfo` returns "temporary failure in name resolution" for every url. In addition, if I restart program from the first 'bad' url, it work again.

I am really confused and stuck for 2 days, I felt that the DNS is working well, but some limited resources have been used up, can any one give me some suggestions?

Comment: When you restart the lookup, does it work for all the rest of the hostnames, or only 6000 again? Is it exactly 6000? Is it the same amount (i.e. 6000) every time?

Comment: Every time it is about 6000 url's, but not exactly the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you calling `freeaddrinfo()` on the returned address information? Very basic, but since you're not showing your code it's the first theory that comes to mind.

Comment: It's also unlikely that a resource leak would manifest like this.

Comment: Finally, I find I forgot to close the socket descriptor in one `if` branch. After correct the bug my program works normally. But still I can't tell why function `socket()` will return correctly instead of post an error

Answer (score 4):

You may be hitting some sort of rate limiting in your DNS server.
As with all network problems, run Wireshark: check if the DNS requests which are failing are actually being sent, and if so, what reply they're getting.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if your ISP has killed your spider on grounds that it is acting very like a worm.

Consider running a local DNS recursor such as [PowerDNS recursor](http://doc.powerdns.com/built-in-recursor.html) that can provide caching of already-retrieved information *and* will perform the lookups entirely itself -- it won't rely on an ISP-provided DNS server, so it is less likely rate-limits on your ISP's equipment will influence your program.